# How to modify the values inside a structure( struct for a vending machine)

Tags: struct

This is code for a operator mode of a coffee machine.By the operator mode operator should be able to add new coffee types and add more coffee powder to the existing coffee types.But I don't know how to access the data inside a structure to modify them(To add more coffee powder).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct coffee {
  string name;
  int itemprice;
  string country;
  int quantity;

};

float remainder, price2, price;

int main() {

      int coffeetype = 1; 

 vector <coffee> coffee_drink ={

   { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
   {"Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20},
   {"Long black", 80, "Austral", 20},
   {"Americano", 100, "America", 20},
   {"Latte", 200, "Italy", 20},
   {"Irishcoffee", 130, "Ireland", 20},
   {"Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20}

   };


   //Add new coffee type
      coffee enter_coffee;
         cout << "Enter the detailsof new coffee here!" << endl
              << "Enter the name of new coffee type"<<endl;
         cin >> enter_coffee.name;
         cout << "Enter the price of new coffee type"<<endl;
         cin >> enter_coffee.itemprice;
         cout << "Enter the country of origin" << endl;
         cin >> enter_coffee.country;
         cout << "Enter the quantity" << endl;
         cin >> enter_coffee.quantity;

         coffee_drink.push_back(enter_coffee);

   //Cout coffee names      
            cout << fixed;
        cout << setprecision(2);   
for (int i = 0; i != coffee_drink.size(); ++i){
        cout<< "\n " << i+1 << ") "<<coffee_drink[i].name<<"\t\t"<<coffee_drink[i].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<coffee_drink[i].country<<"\t\t("<<coffee_drink[i].quantity<<") remaining";}


}
```

By the above code part i can only add a new coffee type..But i want add more coffee powder to the existing coffee types

```
 vector <coffee> coffee_drink ={

   { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
   {"Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20},
   {"Long black", 80, "Austral", 20},
   {"Americano", 100, "America", 20},
   {"Latte", 200, "Italy", 20},
   {"Irishcoffee", 130, "Ireland", 20},
   {"Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20}

   };
```

Here the default number of coffee cups is 20.But when people bye coffee It'll reduce.So here I want add more coffee cups when it is reduced.Could someone help me out with this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly make changes to any coffee type through proper indexing. For eg. To make increase quantity of expresso :

```
coffee_drink[0].quantity += 10;//this will add 10 more cups of coffee
```

You can change quantity of other coffe types similarly.